# AngularJS ng-bind-html doesn't update on value changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) in combination with [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org) (AKA: [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com)) for a Hybrid mobile application and I'm making use of the ng-bind-html feature. The idea was to generate HTML elements based on the value of an Object. However I've noticed that the HTML doesn't "recompile" or whatever when a value is changed, which is causing a major headache for myself.

I'm creating an input field for each value in an array. Then using an array index that can be changed with a button. So for example, array index one may have 3  input fields, but array index 2 may have 5. The issue is that the HTML doesn't update when the index that's used does.

For example, here is some HTML code:

```
<div id="container" ng-bind-html="genHTML()"></div>
<button class="button" ng-click="next()">Current index: {{index}}</button>
```

Here's some JavaScript

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.object = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'] ];
    $scope.index = 0;
    $scope.genHTML = function() {
        var html = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.object[$scope.index].length; i++) {
            html += '<input type="text" ng-model="object[index]['+i+']">';
        }
        return html;
    };

    $scope.next = function() {
        $scope.index++;
    };
}
```

When the button is clicked the value of `$scope.index` is increased, but the input fields generated by `$scope.genHTML` are not updated. How can I fix this issue?

Note: I'm using `bind-html-compile` instead of `ng-bind-html` so that it recompiled the angular directives. Source: https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile

Comment: should be using your own directive for this not `ng-bind-html`. Also could simply use `ng-repeat`

Comment: Your comment doesn't explain anything.

Comment: should be pretty clear...don't use `ng-bind-html` for this use case. Have you tried `ng-repeat`? Otherwise create your own directive

Comment: As already stated, I'm using `bind-html-compile`. ng-repeat does not fit my specific use case, as it's far more complicated than the example provided, and is based on a handful of variables. Elements, classes, and event input types are changed depending on variables inside the object.

Comment: Well the question gave no indication of more complexity. When you oversimplify sample how are we supposed to know? Create a demo that replicates problem. Still seems like creating your own directive would be simpler

Comment: The problem I've asked for help with is replicated in the sample, my complexity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You got code unsafe error in console.?

Comment: @PareshGami No, and `bind-html-compile` allows unsafe code.